# How to extend SeleniumWebDriver into AppiumWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have created a WebDriverWrapper for my web project. This wrapper has a protected variable as :

```
protected WebDriver driver;
```

I have a lot of methods in this wrapper which provides extension over driver's native methods.

Now there is another project but for mobile based on Appium.
Adopting similar approach, I have AppiumDriverWrapper which has a variable as :

`protected AppiumDriver driver;`

Then it has all methods copied over from WebDriverWrapper.
Now I want to make a core framework, which can be used for both Web and Mobile framework.

The problem is I want to do : 
`AppiumDriverWrapper extends WebDriverWrapper`
to have all methods available from WebDriverWrapper.
But in this case, driver comes out to be still of type WebDriver and not AppiumDriver. So in mobile framework, I can't apply any of the methods applicable for AppiumDriver. Although I can use methods applicable to WebDriver.

I can create another variable in AppiumDriverWrapper as :
`protected AppiumDriver appiumDriver` or something but in that case I will have to make changes at  a lot of places.

Comment: I think you simply need a constructor on ```WebDriverWrapper``` that accepts a ```WebDriver``` and call that (super) constructor from ```AppiumDriverWrapper``` constructor.  As far as I can tell from a quick look at the Appium code it is a ```RemoteWebDriver``` which is a ```WebDriver```

Comment: Doing this will set the driver variable in WebDriverWrapper which is of WebDriver type and it will be inherited in AppiumDriverWrapper and if we remove AppiumDriver driver from AppiumDriverWrapper in favor of it, all methods implemented assuming driver is of AppiumDriver will start complaining " could not resolve the method", because they will try to see method on Webdriver instead of AppiumDriver

Comment: No, I don't think so. ```WebDriverWrapper``` has methods that work against a ```WebDriver``` all you are doing is swapping the instance of of ```WebDriver``` when you construct an instance of ```AppiumDriverWrapper```.  This is in essence polymorphism.  ```AppiumDriver``` is a ```WebDriver``` so when constructing an instance of ```AppiumDriverWrapper``` that instance can supply to its base class the ```WebDriver``` instance in this case ```AppiumDriver```.

Comment: I did not even compile, currently methods in appiumdriverwrapper are written against AppiumDriver driver, if we remove it and want to use WebDriver driver, the methods which were written assuming it to be AppiumDriver will complain, i have tried it out, if you want to see, just use sample classes you provided in the deleted comment, implement some method against AppiumDriver and then change it to be Webdriver and see the methods will turn re

Comment: *it did not even compile.